# bootstrap 3 modal in Slick-App-Like-Sliding-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Mmenu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently using a drawer like menu called "Slick-App-Like-Sliding-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Mmenu" in my bootstrap3 site with a sign in button - which calls a modal. However, the modal does not work inside this menu. It works fine so long it sits outside of the slick menu

Any idea how to fix it? I inserted the elseif part but all it does is break the menu - but on the bright side, the modal works..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $menu = $('nav#menu'),
        $html = $('html, body');       
        $menu.mmenu({
            onClick: {
                //  set the location.href after the menu closes
                setLocationHref: function()
                {
                    var href = $(this).attr( 'href' );
                    //  set location.href only if the clicked link is not linked to an anchor
                    return href.slice( 0, 1 ) != '#';
                },

                //  callback after the menu closes
                callback: function()
                {
                    var href = $(this).attr( 'href' );

                    //  if the clicked link is linked to an anchor, scroll the page to that anchor 
                    if ( href.slice( 0, 1 ) == '#' )
                    {
                        setTimeout(
                        function()
                        {
                            $html.animate({
                                scrollTop: $( href ).offset().top
                            }); 
                        }, 10
                    );              
                    }
                    elseif (href.match(/#modalSignin/))
                    {
                        $(href).modal('toggle');
                    }
                }
            },
            configuration: {
                hardwareAcceleration: false
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I can remember in JS you just use the "normal" `else` and `if` statements, there is no statement called `elseif` (other languages have something like that, for example `elseif` in PHP or `elif` in Python). So basically you need a space i.e. `else if` instead of `elseif`.

Comment: you are absolutely right! Else alone works good. Else if didnt. Thanks! If you could make that answer, I can give u some rep.

Comment: Oh ok, I made it just a comment because I wasn't sure it solves your problem, but if it did then I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*since my comment seems to solve the problem, I make an answer with it*

As far as I can remember in JS you just use the "normal" `else` and `if` statements, there is no statement called `elseif` (other languages have something like that, for example `elseif` in PHP or `elif` in Python). So basically you need a space i.e. `else if` instead of `elseif`.